# Как удалить у пачки txt файлов все строки кроме первых 40?

Tags: python, excel, ms-word, notepad++, txt

В папке лежат около 1000 файлов .txt, в них нужно удалить всё, кроме первых 40 строк. После составить таблицу в exel с 40 столбцами(то есть эти строки закинуть в exel и разнести по столбцам в одну строчку) Как  это автоматизировать с помощью word / python / notepad++? Кто-нибудь сталкивался с похожей задачей?

Comment: Ваши попытки решения проблемы где?

Answer (score 1):

С помощью os.listdir() проходитесь по каждому файлу в директории. Потом с помощью контекстного менеджера `with open(file) ...` заходите в каждый файл и удаляете все, кроме первых 40 строк. Дальше в python есть excel api и смотрите как им пользоваться.

Comment: Как удалить все строчки, кроме первых 40? В этом и основная проблема...

Comment: @Adel надо не удалять все строчки кроме первых сорока, а сохранять в новый файл только первые сорок строк.

Comment: with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# Возьмите первые 40 строк (включительно)
first_40_lines = lines[:40]

first_40_lines_str = ''.join(first_40_lines)
print(first_40_lines_str)